# Multiple line comments in MASM assembly

Tags: assembly, comments, masm, masm32

Is there a way to comment multiple lines in assembly?

I am using Masm32 v9.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

you can use the [COMMENT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4c9h3x38%28VS.80%29.aspx) directive to do multi line comments:

```
 COMMENT @
 This is some text
 And some more text
 @
```

make sure to chose a delimiter which is not used in the comment itself ;^)

Comment: MSFT link is broken (as always.) [Here's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/comment-masm?view=vs-2019) an updated one. Also note that the `delimeter` doesn't have to be a single character. It just has to match the ending delimiter in a case-sensitive way.